# Filter rows from one file based on vector

Tags: r

I want to use the into from `negvalues` to filter out rows in `fitted.values.plot`. What I tried is this:

```
fitted.values.plot.filter <- fitted.values.plot[!fitted.values.plot$miRNAs_2,
%in% negvalues,]
```

negvalues:

```
> negvalues
 [1] hsa-mir-135b   hsa-mir-9-2    hsa-mir-9-3    hsa-mir-9-1    hsa-mir-139    hsa-mir-3152   hsa-mir-129-2  hsa-mir-129-1 
 [9] hsa-mir-584    hsa-mir-195    hsa-mir-378a   hsa-mir-30a    hsa-mir-497    hsa-mir-183    hsa-mir-182    hsa-mir-378g  
[17] hsa-mir-21     hsa-mir-31     hsa-mir-378i   hsa-mir-138-2  hsa-mir-138-1  hsa-mir-4662a  hsa-mir-378c   hsa-mir-504   
[25] hsa-mir-19a    hsa-mir-10b    hsa-mir-422a   hsa-mir-218-1  hsa-mir-218-2  hsa-mir-7-1    hsa-mir-25     hsa-mir-204   
[33] hsa-mir-145    hsa-mir-7-3    hsa-mir-1224   hsa-mir-503    hsa-mir-26a-2  hsa-mir-26a-1  hsa-mir-7-2    hsa-mir-92a-1 
[41] hsa-mir-3195   hsa-mir-642a   hsa-mir-149    hsa-mir-125a   hsa-mir-99a    hsa-mir-224    hsa-let-7c     hsa-mir-29b-1 
[49] hsa-mir-215    hsa-mir-135a-1 hsa-mir-4532   hsa-mir-3687   hsa-mir-378d-2 hsa-mir-135a-2
54 Levels: hsa-let-7c hsa-mir-10b hsa-mir-1224 hsa-mir-125a hsa-mir-129-1 hsa-mir-129-2 hsa-mir-135a-1 ... hsa-mir-99a
>
```

fitted.values.plot:

```
> head(fitted.values.plot)
                100              106               122              124               126              134
1 0.689673028877691 2.05061067282612  1.05656799134149 1.75048593733063 0.310608256464213 1.19301227491032
2 0.689964636197034 2.05147771134477  1.05701472906612 1.75122607720905 0.310739587743298 1.19351670396128
3 0.689420828637648 2.04986080371093  1.05618162462874 1.74984581809282 0.310494672963684  1.1925760131319
4 0.819027066280732 2.43522013059115  1.25473629682568  2.0788044504954  0.36886547451107  1.4167718652805
5  1.71613593527086 5.10260154817646  2.62909265996488 4.35579136120192 0.772896674787318 2.96861142957053
6 0.581521608151111 1.72904313525816 0.890881753699624 1.47598261016372 0.261900067482724 1.00592945874486
                141              167              185               192              235              239               243
1 0.867775250152935 1.78201822975849 4.56767147668584  0.88919230295437 1.20614688357531 2.44091589518612 0.453229695574674
2 0.868142162593898 1.78277170211024 4.56960277801154 0.889568270946429 1.20665686619711 2.44194796242832 0.453421330002931
3 0.867457921335906 1.78136657976424 4.56600116656115 0.888867142330624 1.20570581872163 2.44002329891381 0.453063958140798
4   1.0305338726677 2.11625089232931 5.42437707818155  1.05596787572402 1.43236998141843 2.89873041421608 0.538236776522783
5  2.15931351259239 4.43425419487975 11.3658862003178  2.21260626495642 3.00129470553158 6.07381078758356   1.1277862623877
6 0.731694640580416 1.50257015039446 3.85138979111705 0.749753167542404 1.01700435718728 2.05814244909665 0.382156254335941
               246                26              261               267               270              279
1 9.29220635550229 0.917975598997362 1.23335634006278 0.799542483070391 0.280114334869145 14.3542483667977
2 9.29613528308486 0.918363737133027 1.23387782737788 0.799880545355599 0.280232772718505   14.36031762529
3   9.288808373306 0.917639912872592 1.23290532523112 0.799250105671664 0.280011902412698 14.3489992926246
4 11.0350386225875  1.09014972354014 1.46468280269592 0.949503470277195 0.332652158783696 17.0465096303023
5 23.1221007302257  2.28422868109658 3.06900088527496  1.98952768851301 0.697017653185172 35.7181452871246
6 7.83504437155823 0.774022796630335 1.03994694915621 0.674161828971106  0.23618806544365 12.1032797348103
                299              301              305              342               35               350               356
1 0.753129142741628 1.50036484935157  1.4909962305725 2.28269735314694 5.34698835531872 0.755981268961232  1.08750267953744
2 0.753447580553803 1.50099923311524  1.4916266530999 2.28366252247813 5.34924916714631 0.756300912708466  1.08796249705657
3 0.752853737814032  1.4998161946133 1.49045100175897 2.28186261437029 5.34503306391212 0.755704821065611  1.08710500060068
4   0.8943849135495 1.78177102693844 1.77064524409288 2.71083664007729  6.3498614600319 0.897771980278944  1.29147304867556
5  1.87403585705227 3.73340688438915  3.7100946441283 5.68011041907495 13.3050858563655  1.88113289592788  2.70606845550359
6 0.635026819803686 1.26508438560826 1.25718491146553 1.92473502680601 4.50849770391938 0.637431688424655 0.916965403304764
                361               366              367              377              379              388               400
1 0.211085453506283 0.847222381841847 1.30506524028464 1.83280982013158 2.96187312094598 1.86849492946425 0.927319872035087
2 0.211174704587117 0.847580604125905 1.30561704753294 1.83358476816657  2.9631254591481 1.86928496586523 0.927711961113149
3 0.211008263591912 0.846912568815787 1.30458800287924 1.83213959662387 2.96079002057696 1.86781165659436 0.926980768888328
4 0.250676324114233  1.00612613924672 1.54984131653617  2.1765688771035 3.51739759475841 2.21894703194334  1.10124659439366
5 0.525250831926215  2.10817113873598 3.24743648503989 4.56064056900063 7.37012567656856 4.64943699269074  2.30748034105363
6 0.177983982612795 0.714364780585988  1.1004107823492 1.54539683213722 2.49740550712112 1.57548596321423 0.781901742821317
                402                46               48                55                57               60
1 0.917217782115268 0.278406628969608 1.12156870821005 0.389984318352341  1.11390669355888  1.7197525593975
2 0.917605599831052 0.278524344767328 1.12204292951603 0.390149211391357   1.1143776752144 1.72047970459932
3 0.916882373109646 0.278304820988556 1.12115857197796 0.389841708543656  1.11349935917905 1.71912367876836
4  1.08924977166189 0.330624158130626 1.33192845051861 0.463129191343587  1.32282935990787 2.04230676635884
5  2.28234298058451 0.692768312789999 2.79083606787808 0.970410723478138  2.77177042643805 4.27931649256865
6 0.773383817181369  0.23474815429827 0.94568935066465 0.328828732553183 0.939228858670536 1.45006870225191
                 68                70                73                77               82                93
1 0.717084627119229 0.958871302874981 0.874149314497608 0.740455373756385 2.48365414652581 0.999934406893559
2  0.71738782460137 0.959276732518475 0.874518922018322 0.740768452849802 2.48470428434115  1.00035719882496
3 0.716822402981821  0.95852066197323 0.873829654807118 0.740184603383782 2.48274592169214 0.999568749999806
4 0.851579942716058  1.13871576421144  1.03810344694697 0.879334071489469 2.94948458778392   1.1874806023427
5  1.78434511094657  2.38599079746756  2.17517430519642  1.84249930352591 6.18015777501619  2.48816946107968
6 0.604634642913903 0.808505420264441 0.737069152839075 0.624340494236301 2.09417868019165 0.843129193102739
                94      miRNAs_1     miRNAs_2
1 1.35335856597949 hsa-let-7a-5p hsa-let-7a-1
2 1.35393079259561 hsa-let-7a-5p hsa-let-7a-2
3 1.35286366862826 hsa-let-7a-5p hsa-let-7a-3
4 1.60719246586146 hsa-let-7b-5p   hsa-let-7b
5 3.36760634552223 hsa-let-7c-5p   hsa-let-7c
6 1.14113096603789 hsa-let-7d-5p   hsa-let-7d


> str(fitted.values.plot)
'data.frame':   1369 obs. of  48 variables:
 $ 100     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00208423487317347",..: 677 678 675 768 972 573 693 620 622 735 ...
 $ 106     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00619707324579727",..: 752 753 750 846 1078 597 769 645 647 813 ...
 $ 122     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00319301431435754",..: 678 679 676 772 1000 573 695 620 622 739 ...
 $ 124     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.0052900775915819",..: 697 698 695 823 1052 590 714 638 640 758 ...
 $ 126     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00093867750790807",..: 677 678 675 768 954 573 693 620 622 735 ...
 $ 134     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00360535744240779",..: 681 682 679 775 1005 574 698 622 624 742 ...
 $ 141     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00262247088506391",..: 677 678 675 768 997 573 693 620 622 735 ...
 $ 167     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00538537014436763",..: 698 699 696 827 1056 591 715 639 641 759 ...
 $ 185     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.0138037878563998",..: 862 863 860 961 279 744 879 803 805 928 ...
 $ 192     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00268719455332448",..: 677 678 675 768 997 573 693 620 622 735 ...
 $ 235     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00364505104833233",..: 681 682 679 775 1015 574 698 622 624 742 ...
 $ 239     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00737659995129747",..: 766 767 764 860 1100 659 783 707 709 827 ...
 $ 243     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00136968838496083",..: 677 678 675 768 957 573 693 620 622 735 ...
 $ 246     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.0280816266896476",..: 1127 1128 1125 149 445 1007 1144 1062 1064 114 ...
 $ 26      : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00277417946771979",..: 677 678 675 769 998 573 693 620 622 736 ...
 $ 261     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00372727972151037",..: 683 684 681 777 1018 576 700 624 626 744 ...
 $ 267     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00241626721072567",..: 677 678 675 768 977 573 693 620 622 735 ...
 $ 270     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.000846522976489484",..: 677 678 675 768 954 573 693 620 622 735 ...
 $ 279     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.0433794331104381",..: 305 306 303 398 699 193 321 244 246 363 ...
 $ 299     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00227600320380762",..: 677 678 675 768 973 573 693 620 622 735 ...
 $ 301     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00453419607635083",..: 690 691 688 784 1027 583 707 631 633 751 ...
 $ 305     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00450588352655514",..: 690 691 688 784 1027 583 707 631 633 751 ...
 $ 342     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.0068984536571944",..: 759 760 757 853 1088 603 776 700 702 820 ...
 $ 35      : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.0161589320300708",..: 902 903 900 1000 264 785 919 833 835 963 ...
 $ 350     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00228462250698566",..: 677 678 675 768 973 573 693 620 622 735 ...
 $ 356     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00328650086991218",..: 679 680 677 773 1001 573 696 620 622 740 ...
 $ 361     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.000637913395182892",..: 677 678 675 768 954 573 693 620 622 735 ...
 $ 366     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00256035883618851",..: 677 678 675 768 997 573 693 620 622 735 ...
 $ 367     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00394398848682563",..: 685 686 683 779 1021 578 702 626 628 746 ...
 $ 377     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00553886549576888",..: 699 700 697 828 1057 592 716 640 642 795 ...
 $ 379     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00895096515320675",..: 785 786 783 895 1126 678 818 726 728 862 ...
 $ 388     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00564670812004142",..: 699 700 697 831 1059 592 716 640 642 798 ...
 $ 400     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00280241844316787",..: 677 678 675 770 998 573 693 620 622 737 ...
 $ 402     : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00277188929787553",..: 677 678 675 769 998 573 693 620 622 736 ...
 $ 46      : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.000841362182838137",..: 677 678 675 768 954 573 693 620 622 735 ...
 $ 48      : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00338945053153015",..: 679 680 677 773 1000 573 696 620 622 740 ...
 $ 55      : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00117855691359054",..: 677 678 675 768 954 573 693 620 622 735 ...
 $ 57      : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00336629544576333",..: 679 680 677 773 1000 573 696 620 622 740 ...
 $ 60      : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00519719940818688",..: 697 698 695 821 1050 590 714 638 640 758 ...
 $ 68      : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00216707443132959",..: 677 678 675 768 973 573 693 620 622 735 ...
 $ 70      : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00289776883342749",..: 677 678 675 770 998 573 693 620 622 737 ...
 $ 73      : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00264173370474041",..: 677 678 675 768 997 573 693 620 622 735 ...
 $ 77      : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00223770228411448",..: 677 678 675 768 973 573 693 620 622 735 ...
 $ 82      : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00750575761026171",..: 765 766 763 859 1101 658 782 706 708 826 ...
 $ 93      : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00302186409279344",..: 677 678 675 771 998 573 694 620 622 738 ...
 $ 94      : Factor w/ 1171 levels "0.00408993392667926",..: 687 688 685 781 1026 580 704 628 630 748 ...
 $ miRNAs_1: Factor w/ 1208 levels "Cal01","Cal02",..: 11 11 11 12 13 14 15 16 16 17 ...
 $ miRNAs_2: Factor w/ 1230 levels "hsa-let-7a-1",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Comment: should be `fitted.values.plot[!fitted.values.plot$miRNAs_2 %in% negvalues,]` if you are getting an error. I mean omit `,`.

Comment: the problem is that i get too many matches. it does not seem to filter correct

Comment: In that case, please provide a sample data for fitted.values.plot with only some columns and expected output. That way, we can reproduce your error.

Comment: This question does not make sense as stated. What is `negvalues` a vector of (userids?) and how does it correspond to `fitted.values.plot$miRNAs_2`? Show us `str(fitted.values)`

Comment: There must be something with negvalues that makes it match every row in  fitted.values.plot

Comment: I think the user is leaving important information out. The subset worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me:

```
fitted.values.plot[fitted.values.plot$miRNAs_2 %in% negvalues,]
#       X94      miRNAs_1   miRNAs_2
#5 3.367606 hsa-let-7c-5p hsa-let-7c
```

Comment: You have an extra comma in your function. That might be it.

Comment: `fitted.values.plot[!fitted.values.plot$miRNAs_2,
%in% negvalues,]` Why do you have a comma after `mirNAs_2`?

Comment: You didn't read the first comment by user227710? In any case, glad it's solved. Cheers